# Database login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am aware that this question repeats from time to time but I tried almost every response here and I still encounter a problem with code below that tries to connect to my MS SQL Server 2014:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "(LocalDB)\\v11.0";
builder.UserID = "LOGIN";
builder.Password = "PASSWORD";
builder.InitialCatalog = "DATABASE";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

I created an user LOGIN with password PASSWORD:

```
CREATE LOGIN [LOGIN] WITH
PASSWORD=N'PASSWORD',
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DATABASE],
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english],
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
CHECK_POLICY=ON
```

and enable account.

```
alter login LOGIN enable
```

I checked if in my Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio user LOGIN is in Security folder and in Database Secuirty Users folder also contains User LOGIN.

I tried also using Windows Authentication in my Visual Studio to connect to database and I succeeded. However I cannot repeat this connection process with my code above even when I try to execute the code below:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "(LocalDB)\\v11.0";
builder.InitialCatalog = "DATABASE";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

I receive following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'LOGIN'.
    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
    in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

This database is new on my server; I made a new installation yesterday and I used default installation settings as far as I remember.

Comment: What are you using? SQL Server 2014 or Local DB?

Comment: Is the database using windows credentials or sql server credentials?  Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  What does the login window show?  If it shows Windows Authentication then using a login and password will not work.  You are using IntegratedSecurity = true which means the database is using Windows Authentication.  So remove the username and password.  Make sure the DataSource (the instance of the database) in code matches the name in the SSMS login window.  There is a user group in windows credentials for the database and user must be in group.

Comment: If the user can access database from SSMS then the user is in the correct group.  If user cannot access database with SSMS then you have to fix the Windows Credential for user.

Comment: @jdweng *"Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server."*. SSMS stopped "coming with" SQL Server from SQL Server 2014. Since then it has been a separate installation

Comment: I usually install the SQL Full installation for Express which I thought came with SSMS.  I haven't had any comments about SSMS not being installed.

Comment: Are you sure you are poiting to the same server??. On your connection string you are pointing to "(LocalDB)\\v11.0". Aren´t you connecting to (local) with management studio??

Comment: There should be more information in the error log for SQL Server saying why the login failed.

Comment: The SQL Server error log will contain more information about the reason for the login failure. The error log file for LocalDB is in the user AppData directory with a path like `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\V11.0\errorlog`.

Comment: Another (albeit undocumented) way to find login failed messages in the SQL Server error log is with this query: `EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'login';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank you for your answers. Solution is in code below:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = ".";            // DataSource changed             
builder.InitialCatalog = "DATABASE";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few types of authentications in SQL Server like windows, server etc.

The login you created via SQL will try to login via SQL Server authentication mode. So make sure your SQL Server allows use that type of the authentication.

You can check you SQL server settings:

Right click on server name -> Properties -> Security:

Mixed mode authentication should allow both windows and server:

[image]