# Login Failed for User when trying to Open() a SqlConnection in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection, sqlconnection

I'm using Sql Server 2017 and Visual Studio 2017. I transferred my database from my PC to my friend's laptop using Generate Scripts. I use the following code **in my friend's laptop** when trying to connect to said database in the laptop:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = PresentasiDB; Integrated Security = True; Trusted_Connection = True;"))
            {              
                DataTable orderTable = new DataTable();                
                SqlDataAdapter sqlda;

                string insertOrder = "INSERT INTO \"Order\" DEFAULT VALUES";
                using (SqlCommand newOrder = new SqlCommand(insertOrder, sqlCon))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    newOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM \"Order\" ORDER BY OrderID DESC", sqlCon);
                sqlda.Fill(orderTable);

                orderID = Convert.ToInt32(orderTable.Rows[0][0]);                
            }
```

However, this failed. The failure occurred in the `sqlCon.Open()` part. I've tried using SQL Server login Authentication and Windows Authentication. Both failed. Someone, please help me.

Comment: As you said you have moved database to your friend's PC so you need to use Data Source for his machine.

Comment: Have you checked permission for imported DB, You can do it from MSSMS.

Comment: @Gaurav How do I use the Data Source for my friend's machine? Doesn't `(local)` work get my friend's Data Source automatically. Please help :-( I'm really not good at this.

Comment: @Hasitha Could you provide me a link please? I'm really totally oblivious about SQL Server.

Comment: You need to ask your friend to create a sql login for you and then from your sql server try to connect to his sql server and then use same Data source and credentials in your connection.

Comment: @Gaurav Oh sorry, I meant to say that I was trying to run said code in my friend's laptop, not my PC.

Comment: Please see [my approach to SQL login problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958501/database-login-failed-for-user).

Comment: I have added answer for you with screenshot.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer Go to MSSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio). Connect to the local instance. Expand Databases -> Click on the restored DB-> Right click on and go to properties. Check Permission tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the data source you need to specify server name you use to connect to sql server. [image]

As shown in the screen the datasource here is "gaurav.goel

Comment: Hi, I've gotten said server name, it's DESKTOP-JK6NCPT\MSSQLSERVER1. I'm trying to run the code with that Data Source now.

Comment: It still failed :-(

Comment: are you using windows authentication as show in screenshot or sql sever authentication? If you are using sql sever authentication then you need to specify User name and password in the connection.

Comment: @sepupic Login failed for User 'user name'.

Comment: @Gaurav I'm using Windows Authentication. Integrated security = true means using Windows Authentication, right?

Comment: You should open SQL Server error log (even with notepad) and seek it for the error "login failed". The cause of this error is written in the next row

Comment: Let's try one more way to check the connectivity, create a text file on your machine and change its extension to UDL. Now double click this file and it will ask for database credentials similar to SQL server, using this you can verify whether you can connect or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try your connecting string something like this (for sa login)

```
string connstr = userid=sa;password=sapassword;server=localhost,1433;database=PresentasiDB;Trusted_Connection=no
```

To test it did you try entering the server as 'localhost' from management studio?